# what's wrong with this function? it shows no error but keeps giving output as 0

Tags: c++, string, function, vector

A string is said to be a child of a another string if it can be formed by deleting 0 or more characters from the other string. Given two strings of equal length, what's the longest string that can be constructed such that it is a child of both?

For example, ABCD and ABDC have two children with maximum length 3, ABC and ABD. They can be formed by eliminating either the D or C from both strings. Note that we will not consider ABCD as a common child because we can't rearrange characters and ABCD  ABDC.

commonChild has the following parameter(s):

s1, s2: two equal length strings

Print the length of the longest string , such that  is a child of both strings.

**Sample Input**

> ```
> HARRY
> SALLY
> ```

**Sample Output**

> ```
> 2
> ```

I wrote this following function using vector funcs.

```
int commonChild(string s1, string s2) {

    vector <char> v1; vector <char> v2; vector <char> v3;
    for(int i=0;i<s1.size();i++)
    {
        v1.push_back(s1[i]);
    }

    for(int j=0;j<s2.size();j++)
    {
        v2.push_back(s2[j]);

    }

    set_intersection(v1.begin(),v1.end(),v2.begin(), v2.end(), v3.begin());
    return(v3.size());
}
```

**it shows no error. but the ouput is always 0. what's going wrong?**

Comment: Read some [documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/set_intersection). Pay special attention to the word "sorted".

Comment: Btw that's not a correct solution if I got what you meant. Your code should return `2` for the test `AB BA`, but the answer is `1`.

Comment: Also note that you will need to reserve the space in your `v3` to store the intersections. See the possible implementations in the posted documentation.

Comment: Apart from the bugs in your code, `std::set_intersection` simply doesn't solve the problem you've been given. I think you're going to have to work a bit harder. Some kind of recursive function seems the correct approach.

Comment: That's a "longest common substring" problem. You can try to google it to find out how to write a correct solution.

Comment: You don't need to copy the elements of a `std::string` into a `std::vector<char>`, `string` has all the members of `vector`, with the same meanings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a number of problems.

First is that you can't add elements to a `vector` through it's `iterator`, so `v3.begin()` isn't a suitable input to `std::set_intersection`. For the `d_first` parameter of `set_difference` either start with a non-empty `v3`, or use [`std::back_inserter`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/back_inserter).

Second, [`std::set_intersection`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/set_intersection) requires sorted input, which your sample input isn't. Sorting your input will give a different meaning to your function.

Thirdly, whilst not wrong, it is pointless to copy a `std::string` into a `std::vector<char>`. `std::string` is a container type.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is here:

```
set_intersection(v1.begin(),v1.end(),v2.begin(), v2.end(), v3.begin());
                                                           ^
                        This iterator is invalid ----------+
```

The `v3` vector is empty and it is not valid to pass `v3.begin()` as the output iterator of `set_intersection()`.

Replace with `back_inserter(v3)` to obtain an output iterator that will insert elements into `v3`.

```
set_intersection(v1.begin(),v1.end(),v2.begin(), v2.end(), back_inserter(v3));
```

See it running [there](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/94b1c33615a3319d).

*References:*

- [back_inserter](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/back_inserter) on cppreference

*Notes*

- I only address your question. It doesn't mean that this is the only problem in your code.
- [set_intersection](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/set_intersection) is probably not the right tool here.

Comment: yeah perfect. i know its not the right solution to the problem, just wanted to know why intersection did not give any value.